# Game center display with wrong orientation

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm trying to integrate gamecenter into my application. 
It works fine on iPad, but on iPhone, the game center view is partially displayed, with a wrong orientation. See : http://cl.ly/image/2b241H210T3E

Here is how I call the view:

```
    GKLeaderboardViewController *lb = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (lb != nil) {
    lb.category = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_overall", [AppSettings appleGameCenterId]];
    lb.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:lb animated:YES];
}
[lb release];
```

I also tried to sub class GKLeaderboardViewController like this:

.h:

```
 @interface ITGKLeaderboardViewController : GKLeaderboardViewController 
 @end
```

.m:

```
@interface ITGKLeaderboardViewController ()

@end

@implementation ITGKLeaderboardViewController


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}


@end
```

But it's still the same result.

Any idea ? 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fond how to fix it.

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

I had the exact same problem with MFMailComposeViewController, and the same line resolved the issue.